# Where did the number of initial plaintexts required for impossible cryptanalysis on Mini-AES came from?

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, differential-analysis

I'm implementing impossible differential cryptanalysis on AES and I've started with implementing it on mini-AES to fully understand the process using [R.Phan's paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/IMPOSSIBLE-DIFFERENTIAL-CRYPTANALYSIS-OF-MINI-AES-Phan/db1f8adc50b84393b302eb8db2ca3880d9263556) as a reference.

But I don't understand the initial pairs preperation step:
[image: ![first step of impossible differential cryptanalysis on Mini-AES]

In the paper the author say to obtain $2^{13}$ plaintext $P$ and another $2^{13}$ plaintext $P^{'}$ which are equal in the second and third nibble and from those plaintexts we can obtain $2^{13}$ pairs.

But where did the $2^{13}$ come from if the input difference of the differential trail has two active nibbles and each nibble is $4\;bits$ so we have $2^8$ possible input differences for the pairs ?

Comment: In fact in the public (non paywall) version of the paper available on the author's page https://www.geocities.ws/dearphael/ImpMiniAES.pdf the same argument starts with *obtain $2^{11}$ plaintexts P and P’ which are equal in the second and third nibble and differ in the other nibbles. Since each P and P’ forms a pair with passive second and third nibbles while the first and third nibbles are active, we then have $2^{11}$ such pairs.*

Comment: so the author himself presents two inconsistent versions.

Comment: where does $2^{11}$ comes from? do we take variations of passive nibble or we just use a constant value and only change active varitaions ? @kodlu

Comment: That's exactly what's unclear to me, and it seems the author has two versions of the same claim.

Comment: well, regardless of the paper what do you think the number of the initial pairs should be? @kodlu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of the initial plaintext $2^{13}$ was chosen to satisfy the final equation:
[image]
[image]
[image]

so using all the probabilites mentioned in the paper and if we put $2^{x-7}$ instead of $2^{6}$ in the final equation we'll get:
$$ 2^{8}(1-2^{-3})^{2^{x-7}} \approx 2^{8}e^{-2^{x-7-3}} \approx 0$$

By plotting this equation we'll get:
[image]

So the minimum value of $x=13$ and thus the number of initial plaintext should be $2^{13}$.